# How to do the /ride command in mine craft?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I want to put a baby polar bear on a panda. How can I accomplish this with `/ride`, and how does it work?

Comment: Please do some research before asking a question. I'm assuming you're on Bedrock Edition because `/ride` only exists there.

Answer (score 3):

## You can't.

This command only works for things that would be normally allowed to ride each other, and polar bears can't ride pandas. If you try to this happens:

[image: Riders that did not meet conditions: Polar Bear]